# Spring application not able to getResourceAsStream in external library but can load from own class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classpath, classloader

I am using a library in which a peace of code executes

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.properties")
```

It returns null and when I run same peace of code in my own class it runs fine i.e it is able to read properties file.

I have checked that my jar is part of classpath in my own class.

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

I face this problem only on a remote host. I have included my jar along with all the jar dependencies in a 'jars' folder and for classpaths while running java program I pass /jars/* as classpath argument.

I have spent a lot of time on this, reading about classloaders and classpath but still not able to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How you are building jar?

Comment: I simply run mvn clean install and I use maven-assembly-plugin to put all jar dependencies including mine in a jars folder and then put in tar.gz file and ftp to host

Comment: Please share your pom file.